# Want to find the distinct lines between two files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two files abc.log and xyz.log

abc.log has something like:

```
error: 142
error: 143
error: 144
error: 100
error: 142
```

and file errors.log has content

```
error: 140
error: 143
error: 142
error: 144
error: 156
```

---

I want to list the error that is not present in abc.log and is present in error.log. abc.log file can have multiple repeating errors.

I am writing a shell script and a one liner would help. 
Thanks 
Ambarish

Answer (score 2):

```
fgrep -v -f abc.log xyz.log
```

fgrep reads matches from file.

-v prints non matching content

Comment: This is probably the simplest option.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
comm -13 <(sort abc.log | uniq) <(sort errors.log | uniq)
```

**Explanation**

- `comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2` compares the (sorted) files `FILE1` and `FILE2` line by line. Without options it produces a three-column output: lines only in `FILE1`, lines only in `FILE2` and lines in both files. With `-1` the first column and with `-3` the third column is not shown, so `-13` only shows lines unique to `FILE2`.
- The construct `<(COMMAND)` is called process substitution (works at least with `bash` and `zsh`). It takes the output of `COMMAND` and provides a named pipe or file (depending on the capabilities of the system) with the output as content
- `sort FILE | uniq` (alternatively `sort -u`, if your `sort` supports it) sorts `FILE` as required by `comm and removes duplicate lines. With duplicates lines, that also are contained in the first file but just appear more often in the second file, would also be shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' abc.log errors.log
```

will do the job, and output:

```
error: 140
error: 156
```

idea is save `abc.log` in a hashtable, for each line in `errors.log` check if the hashtable `a` doesn't contain the line, print.